# Get Current User from JWT Authentication on Mux

Tags: go

I'm beginner with Go, ruby my previous language. I started with Mux for build an API. Now I'm learning authentication using JWT to protect the API. Firstly I try to handle authentication in a function with single file `main.go`

```
func ListPosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  // verify authentication here
  // other stuff to get list of posts by a user authentication here
}

func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/posts", ListPosts).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", myRouter))
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

Everything is working well, the above implementation is repeating the authentication every I create a new endpoint, so I'm trying to make it DRY

Here is my `main.go` now :

```
func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/posts", jwt.Authenticate(controllers.ListPosts)).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", myRouter))
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

this is the jwt package I have made :

```
package jwt

func Authenticate(handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // checking header Authorization here
     
    token, err := ValidateToken(r)
    if err != nil {
      // checking signature invalid here
      // checking expire token here
      // response error here
    }

    if !token.Valid {
      // response error here
    }

    getClaim := token.Claims.(*Token)

    // I'm using https://github.com/Kamva/mgm (mongo)
    user := &models.User{}
    coll := mgm.Coll(user)

    // Find and decode the doc to a user model here
    

    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    return
  }
}
```

The authentication is working well, and now I want to get a user authentication in controllers package, do I need to put an UID of user on header and find a user with it? I believe that make a redudant, because I have find a user on `Authenticate` function.

```
package controllers

func ListPosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   // should I find a user with r.Header["UID"] here ?
   w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
   _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode({})
}
```

Comment: You should have the user id in the token. The auth middleware (`Authenticate` function) should extract that user ID, and put it in the request context, so the actual handlers can use it. There are other ways to do it, but this is common and straightforward.

Comment: do you mean, I should set to the context like `context.Set(r, UserId, getClaim.userId)` and get in handlers .. can I set a struct (`user := &models.User{}`) to it?

Comment: You can put the user struct in request context, and use that context downstream: `ctx:=r.Context(), ctx.Set("user",userStruct); r=r.WithContext(ctx)`. Then handlers can get the user struct from request context.